# Acceso personalizado en Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring, spring-security, autenticación

Alguien podría ayudarme en un acceso mediante Spring Security, requiero que la autentificación (Login) se realice mediante un procedimiento almacenado (SP), el cual retorna un carácter 'V' o 'F' según sea el caso.

¿Cómo le digo a Spring Security que intérprete el retorno del SP en el acceso de los roles de usuarios y conventir esa interpretación en una sesión de Spring?

La mayoria de los ejemplos implementan un acceso similar al siguiente:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

Answer (score 2):

La autenticación en Spring Security se realiza por medio de un AuthenticationProvider, que es quien procesa una petición de autenticación devolviendo un objeto con sus credenciales. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
  throws AuthenticationException {
    String user = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new HashSet<>();
    // autentica con tu procedimiento PLSQL a traves de un DAO o lo que sea
    if (callPlSqlDao()=="V") {
        //Aqui le das los roles que correspondan
        grantedAuths .add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
    } else {
        throw new AuthenticationException("No ha sido posible la autenticacion");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }

  private String callPlSqlDAO() {
    ....
  }

}
```

Esto luego lo debes configurar en el xml o en la clase de configuración correspondiente, por ejemplo:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <http-basic/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="MyAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda